# Bootstrap 100% width / Full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a new website with Bootstrap and I need it to be 100% in width, but I do not want it to be fluid. At least not for now.

The issue I have is: using bootstrap standard limits you to 960px and with a fluid layout it is full width but behaves like a fluid layout should by moving elements to become stacked when the window is shrunk in size.

Is there a way to have 100% width with a static bootstrap layout?

Comment: just change .container to the size you need?

Comment: 100% is always a relative value. You should change the container width in pixels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 100% width ... static

This is a bit of an oxymoron. A 100% width layout isn't static.

Bootstrap uses a `.container` class to set a predefined width. Increase this to your desired page width if you want it to be greater than it's default. Be careful though that the sizing of Bootstrap's `span*` and `offset*` classes will need their widths adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes you're right it is an oxymoron so I guess what I really am asking is how can I have a fluid layout that does not stack the spans.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stack the spans"? Bootstrap has 12 different `span*` sizes. `.span1` can fit 12 times within one line of `.container`, and `span12` fits just once, respectively. As long as your `span*` elements do not exceed the span-width of their container you shouldn't have them stacking.

Comment: An example Bootstrap layout could be: `container (row (span12 (row (span6 (row (span3, span3)), span6 (row (span2, span4)))))`. Note that the `row` class is used to determine a new row of elements, and without it the margins would exceed the limit of the container.

Answer (score 19):

This is easy to achieve in Bootstrap 3, just replace the `.container` div with your own:

```
.my-fluid-container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks to Erik Flowers for the heads-up:
http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction#fluid

***UPDATE***

Bootstrap 3 now offers a built-in fluid container class, just use `<div class="container-fluid">`. [See docs.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Answer (score 3):

Just don't include the `bootstrap-responsive.css` in order to disable the responsive function.

If you don't want a `.container` gutter/margin you can put your content outside the container but keep in mind you must maintain your content layout by yourself(still can use grid but lost an ability to centering your content) and don't forget most of the Bootstrap component like `.navbar` need `.container` to control its width.

One of my work need a full screen carousel to holding all contents so I wrap my content with `.container` to center the content.

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Totally fixed my issue.  .row>.container>.content

Answer (score 3):

I can't quite figure out how to reply to the main question, but here's what you want OP

As said above, don't use .container, use your own class like:

```
.my-fluid-container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then when you build your grid, just use col-xs-* for the columns. You will now have a 100% width site that doesn't stack in the "mobile" view. Welcome to the 90's ;)

Comment: This is for Bootstrap 3 - the original question and answer seem to be for bootstrap 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is you don't want margin/padding on the sides. (that's the only way your message makes sense - a 100% width will take the full size of the screen so it will never be static - the size will change depending on how big the window is)

We don't have a use-case or JSFiddle from you so I can't give you exact code but you need to make sure your body has margin:0 and padding:0 and then look for the other divs with Firebug or Chrome Web Dev tools.

If you want your layout to be fluid but stop at a certain point growing, then you need to apply max-width:1000px (for example) to your body or your general container/wrapper element.