# 100% width for only 1 page, leave the rest as fluid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an ASP.NET MVC5 web app. The default template uses bootstrap, which is fine for almost all of the pages. However I need one page to have `width: 100%`.

The view I would like to use this is a partial view, so it will be rendered in the `.container` (see code below), as well as the other partial views.

```
<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

All of them are fine to be fluid, but I need this one to be 100% width. What is an elegant way to do it?

Comment: Do all of the other pages share that same .container div?

Comment: Yes. All pages are rendered in the place of @RenderBody(). The widht of .container is dynamically maintained by bootstrap, based on the current window size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204976/bootstrap-100-width-full-width

Check this post...

Comment: You can override bootstrap style and set 100% width for .container.

Comment: I only need it to be 100% at one page, and leave the others as they are.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, where the container was used in the Layout and fine for most pages, but I wanted an odd full width element within that container.

As of Bootstrap 3, you can use the `.container-fluid` class for 100% width content. However, using this within `.container` does nothing, as it is limited by the `.container` width. Here are a few options/workarounds I've come across:

## Use sections

If the 100% width content is always used at the beginning or end of the container content, you could define sections in the layout page, and insert the 100% width element in there.

**Layout:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    @RenderSection("containerFluid", required: false)
</div>

<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**View:**

```
@section containerFluid
{
    <div>Full width content.</div>
}

<div>Other content</div>
```

In your case, if you had no other content on that one page, you could just put the whole page in the section.

## Use another layout page

If it's a whole page that needs to be full width, you could just get it to use a different layout. Use partials for the common code and change the `.container` element to `.container-fluid`.

**Normal layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@Html.Partial("_LayoutHead")
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")

    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("Footer")
</body>
</html>
```

**Alternative layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@Html.Partial("_LayoutHead")
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")

    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("Footer")
</body>
</html>
```

## Manually close the container and reopen later

I wouldn't really recommend this one, as it's very hacky, and will show up errors, but it does compile and work. This can be used if you have an element somewhere in the middle of the content that you want to be full width for whatever reason.

**View:**

```
<div>Some normal content here.</div>

</div> <!--This shows an error for missing a starting tag. The actual starting tag is on the layout page.-->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>Full width div</div>
</div>

<div class="container"> <!--This shows an error for missing an ending tag. It actually gets closed using the end tag in the layout page-->
    <div>Back to normal</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Create a new _Layout page in the Shared folder (Right click Shared > Add > New Item > select "MVC 5 Layout Page (Razor)"). After the file is created use that layout at the top of your cshtml page: `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutFullWidth.cshtml"; }`.  I copied the default _Layout page's contents and changed `<div class="container body-content">` to `<div class="container-fluid body-content">`

Answer (score 2):

In your partial view, you can use jQuery to modify the CSS of the container div. This would change the width whenever that view is rendered, but would no effect on other pages.

EDIT: As the OP pointed out, Bootstrap's JS will reset the width on window resize. So we have to do the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     setWidthOfContainer();
     $(window).resize(setWidthOfContainer);
});

function setWidthOfContainer(){
     console.log("Setting width of container to 100%.");
     $('div.container').css('width','100%');
}
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GqRd7/

Comment: Thanks, but not good, because on window resize, bootstrap would take care of `.container` and resize it again.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't want to go this way of "programatically fighting against bootstrap".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by making the position of the rendered content `absolute` and `left: 0`, but `<footer>` is hidden behind it, so I have to take care of that one separatelly (or remove it altogether). Not the elegant solution I was wishing for, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the razor code to change the page's style in _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<div class="container" style="@(ViewData["Title"] == "Page1" ? "max-width: 100%;" : "")">
```

Replace "Page1" with your real page title.